# Getting value of SQL Server Output parameter using PDO & ODBC

Tags: php, sql, parameters, pdo, output

I've been learning PHP by adding some functionality to one of my company's web pages to validate user input of SSN before inserting a new record into the database.  That part is working fine.  The database insert involves calling a SQL Server stored procedure that has an output parameter that returns the GUID of the new record for use in a subsequent process.  The database insert part works but when I echo the value of the returned parameter it's an empty string.

Here are pertinent details:
    SQL Server 2008 running on a separate server
    WAMP Server 2.2 running on a Windows 64 PC
    PHP 5.3.1
    Apache 2.2.22

Here is my PHP code:

```
$conn = new PDO( "odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;Database=xxxxx;charset=UTF-8'", "uid", "pwd");

if(!$conn) {
    die( "<br />Error connecting to SQL Server");
}

$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$resource_id = "";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("{CALL xxxx.dbo.app_sp_insert_rq(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $survey_text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $event_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $type_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $folder_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $has_details, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $resource_id, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 100); 

$stmt->execute();

echo $resource_id;
```

Here is the stored procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[app_sp_insert_rq]
    @survey_text nvarchar(max),
    @event_date nvarchar(20),
    @type_id nvarchar(100),
    @description nvarchar(100),
    @folder_id nvarchar(100),
    @has_details nchar(1),
    @uid nvarchar(100),
    @resource_id nvarchar(100) output

AS

select @resource_id = NEWID()

insert into
    xxxxx.dbo.app_events (
        resource_id,
        event_date, 
        [type_id], 
        [description], 
        folder_id, 
        has_details, 
        [uid], 
        survey_text
    )
    values (
        @resource_id,
        @event_date, 
        @type_id, 
        @description, 
        @folder_id, 
        @has_details, 
        @uid, 
        @survey_text
    )
```

Any help will be much appreciated.  I only got this far via multiple searches but this is one roadblock I haven't been able to figure a way around.

Answer (score 1):

It should work - according to [PDO's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1003).
But, it's said that `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` stands for an `INOUT` parameter, while you are using an `OUT`.

You could try this way - as explicitly setting the `$length` parameter (while leaving the `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`) is triggering the `OUT` mode;

```
$stmt->bindParam(8, $resource_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
```

But i think that it *should* work as `INOUT` too (as you wrote your code originally).

Maybe the PDO driver (or the ODBC one) at C level does not support the output parameter binding (as in PDO-MySQL).

But if this is the only `OUT` parameter in your procedure, you could use a function:

```
SELECT func(?, ?, ..., ?) AS result
```

+1: Maybe you are interested in [this comment on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php#101323)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't recognize the concept of input-output parameters, only input or output, and of course PHP doesn't have output only, just input-output, or if I'm not mistaken, no parameter for input only.  As you say, it really should work, but I'll try your suggestion when I finish a couple of other tasks I'm working on.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.  Maybe I will have to write a function.  Was hoping to use the existing code.

Comment: I took the easy way out and removed the output parameter from the stored procedure and added this:

select @resource_id

to the end of the procedure.  Now I have access to the value I need in the PHP code.